# Where is the .whl file after building Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I have just built Tensorflow from source and cannot find the generated .whl file. I have followed the [provided instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources) under Ubuntu 16.10, CPU only, and completed the process without any error. As per instructions, I should find the .whl file under **/tmp/tensorflow_pkg**, but that is not the case (even the directory is not there).

Steps I followed:

- cloned the repository with **git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow**
- selected the r1.0 branch with **git checkout r1.0**
- configured the build to use python3, everything else left to default
- built the PIP package for CPU only with **bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package**

Process completed with:

```
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package
INFO: Elapsed time: 2376.046s, Critical Path: 1360.14s
```

Still I cannot find the .whl output file. What did I do wrong? Or where is the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pls use the following command:

```
sudo bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/
sudo pip install --upgrade /tmp/tensorflow_pkg/tensorflow-1.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: Problem is I built tensorflow with Python 3.5.  How come the name isn't reflecting that?